# Tomcat. Java runtime compile

Tags: java, tomcat, runtime

I create web application where user can input Java source code in input area and send it to server. 
After that I create file `User.java` (by default this file created in `C:\Tomcat-8.0.36\bin`) and compile it in runtime through `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac User.java")`. It's successfully compile.
Then I try to run in Runtime `User.class` through `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java User")`, but I get error message: `"Could not find or load main class User"`. Although I can correct run this file with the help of cmd of this directory `C:\Tomcat-8.0.36\bin`. Also I try to run bat file from code (for example mspaint - successfully run paint - it is mean that correct workspace), but when I run bat file with "`java User`" - it is failed.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should try java -cp . User

Comment: @freefall thanks. It is work. Can you describe it as a response?

Comment: @freefall, can you explain that is going on here, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should try "java -cp . User" that why you're making sure that User class is on classpath - by -cp . you're putting current folder on the cp.